# How can I clear back stack exactly before quit the application in Android?

Tags: android

How can I do that? I know that it can be done with

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

this, but it start a new activity through intent, but I want to quit the application.

Code:

```
intent = new Intent();
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                activity.startActivity(intent);
                activity.finish();
```

NOTE: I'm doing in non-activity class so that's why `activity.finish();`

Comment: @JakeB I already did in above line

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK 
|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
activity.startActivity(intent);
            activity.finish();
```

Comment: but it is starting a new activity! what about that? what will it find in background if I don't specify source n destination? what it will start?

Comment: I think you are working with fragments so you can use
 
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); // or 'getSupportFragmentManager();'
int count = fm.getBackStackEntryCount();
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {    
    fm.popBackStack();
} 
in your activity

Answer (score 0):

To quit application call `finishAffinity()`. By using this you can clear all the back stacks.

Otherwise,

From your current activity call following code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityOne.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); //This will clear back stack
intent.putExtra("QUIT_CURRENT_ACTIVITY", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your `ActivityOne` call following lines of code in `onCreate(...)`  method.

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("QUIT_CURRENT_ACTIVITY", false)) {  //Default should be false
    finish();
}
```

hope this will work for you.

Comment: Are you using fragments or activities?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
System.exit(0);
```